# How to use property value as textarea value in struts 2

Tags: struts2

Instead of just displaying list values using `<s:property/>`, i need to display it in textarea.The reason why i am doing this is `<s:property/>` does not have "name" attribute in order to submit the values to the action class. Is there any way to do that.I wrote down piece fo code below to make it clear so that you can understand  my requirement though it is wrong.Please help me.

```
<s:iterator value="map"   status="stat">

<s:textarea value="<s:property/>" />    

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: `value` is `java.util.Map`? `Map<String, String>`?

Comment: It is ArrayList.I just named it as map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Jagan** said, assume that `map` is `java.util.List`

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="stat">
    <s:textarea value="%{top}" />
</s:iterator>
```

**or**

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="stat">
    <s:textarea>
        <s:param name="value">
            <s:property/>
        </s:param>
    </s:textarea>
</s:iterator>
```

**or**

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="stat">
    <s:textarea>
        <s:param name="value">
            ${top}
        </s:param>
    </s:textarea>
</s:iterator>
```

---

> **@Jagan** : if it is map how to do this ?

Assume map is `java.util.Map`

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="stat">
    <s:textarea value="%{key}" />
    <!-- or -->
    <s:textarea value="%{value}" />
</s:iterator>
```

---

**[IteratorComponent](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/components/IteratorComponent.html)**

```
if (value == null && begin == null && end == null) {
    value = "top";
}
```

`top` is not a attribute of `iterator` and not a keyword of `OGNL`. (I may be wrong)

**top** : top of Stack / element of the current iteration

e.g.

```
<s:property value="top" />
```

or

```
<s:property value="[0].top" />
```

---

**[Iterator tag examples](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html)** of Struts2 **[Cookbook](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/cookbook.html)** have better explanation

Comment: if it is map how to do this ?

Comment: Where is %{top} / ${top} coming from?

Comment: I think it ( %{top} ) is taking the values from the list using iterator.